# Find last entry in a map

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary

I have a

```
QMap<qreal,int> myMap;
```

I need to find the largest key.

Is this the only way ? I was hoping for something built in maybe. Is this good enough ? Isn't creating an iterator for a simple operation too much ?

```
qreal maxkey() 
{ 
    QMap<qreal,int>::iterator it = myMap.end() - 1;
    return it.key(); 
}
```

Edit - I have to use 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`lastKey`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#lastKey):

> `const Key & QMap::lastKey() const`
>
> Returns a reference to the largest key in the map. This function assumes that the map is not empty.
>   This executes in logarithmic time.
>   This function was introduced in Qt 5.2.

As in:

```
qreal last = myMap.lastKey();
```

Comment: what is the difference between yours and my code except for the extra test ?

Comment: oh i see correction... that is what i was looking for

Comment: I am sorry... I am forced to use 4.8

Comment: @Thalia Well then use `end() - 1`

Comment: Thanks, I will keep your info for when I can upgrade to higher qt version.